# Buddypress - New user type with no profile and can't interact but can be admin of a group

Tags: users, buddypress

I need an easy way to create a set of users who cannot interact with the other users, all they can do is administrate a group (they can upload documents to the group-documents plugin and maybe change the name and description and avatar).

Apart from that they're not allowed to have a profile, they're not allowed to interact with other users, post to groups or anything. All they can do is log in and administrate their group.

Any ideas? I'd greatly prefer to create this in plugin format, and don't really want to edit any core files.

Thanks for any help.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to be able to choose the type 
You'll need to write your own registration logic

After that check via get_user_meta() to see if they have a certain permission

if they can do xyz and allow accordingly. I've done custom user types before for a plugin i wrote.

There's no build in roles in BP AFAIK but a lot can be done via actions and filters, does require some coding skills though.

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: If you need it from the backend just create a plugin that lets you modify the users the frontend checks would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had to do something similar. There's a plugin that allows you to add user roles, then I had to test against that role to restrict use of the site.